# How to compare 2 strings containing same characters

Tags: java

My question is that, I have 2 strings, say String1 & String2. Now I want to check whether these 2 strings contain same characters or not, irrespective of their sequence.

Suppose `String1= "qwerty"`, `String2= "qywter"`. Now these Strings contain same characters but are in different sequence. So is there any function that can be used to show that these strings contain same characters?? Can equals() method do that???

All help is appreciated.

Comment: What should the result be in the case where they have the same characters, but not the same number of characters? (Such as "qwerty" and "qywtery"?) They contain the same characters, but not the same number of characters.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
char[] chars1 = string1.toCharArray();
char[] chars2 = string2.toCharArray();
Arrays.sort(chars1);
Arrays.sort(chars2);

return Arrays.equals(chars1, chars2);
```

Comment: @prasad - I did not understand your comment

Comment: i mean, do "return Arrays.equals(chars1, chars2);" statement
 return a boolean value or an int??

Answer (score 2):

You can use `String.equals`, albeit indirectly. First you need a helper method:

```
// given a String, sorts its chars and return it as another String
public static String sorted(String s) {
    char[] arr = s.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    return new String(arr);
}
```

Then you can have:

```
    String s1 = "qwerty";
    String s2 = "qywter";

    System.out.println(sorted(s1)); // eqrtwy

    System.out.println(sorted(s1).equals(sorted(s2))); // true
```

Note that this is not the most efficient algorithm -- it's `O(N log N)` time, and uses extraneous space -- but should work fine for short strings. For long strings, you'd want to go through each `char` (or Unicode code points) manually (instead of `toCharArray()`), and perhaps use the linear-time [counting sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort).

If you don't care about specific character counts matching (e.g. `"xxxyyy"` and `"xy"` has the same chars, albeit in different numbers), then you can use a set-like representation ([`java.util.BitSet`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html)).

```
// given a string, returns its used char set as a java.util.BitSet
public static BitSet usedChar(String s) {
    BitSet bs = new BitSet();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        bs.set(s.charAt(i));
    }
    return bs;
}
```

Then you can have:

```
    System.out.println(
        usedChar("xxxyyy").equals(usedChar("xy"))
    ); // true

    System.out.println(
        usedChar("xyz").equals(usedChar("abc"))
    ); // false
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends whether you actually want characters or you really want code points, and then it matters whether you want to count duplicates or not.  Here's one solution:

```
public class a {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s1 = "qwerty";
    String s2= "qywter";
    System.out.println(codePointSet(s1).equals(codePointSet(s2)));
  }
  public static Set<Integer> codePointSet(String s) {
    Set<Integer> set = new TreeSet<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0, cp; i < s.length(); i += Character.charCount(i)) {
      cp = s.codePointAt(i);
      set.add(cp);
    }
    return set;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] f = new int[(int)char.MaxValue];
foreach (var c in string1) f[(int)c]++;
foreach (var c in string2) f[(int)c]--;
return f.Max() == 0 && f.Min() == 0;
```

This is preferable solution when string1.length() >> char.MaxValue and it has lower big O notation complexity.

**EDIT** this is actually C# code but you can easly achieve similar result in `Java`.

Comment: Interesting approach, though certainly not Java.

Answer (score 0):

`String.equals()` won't work for your particular case. You will likely need to write your own method to equate strings in this way.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a long string that you need to compare, and you don't need a guarantee of success, you can do something like this:

1. make sure the strings are the same length
2. for each image
3. add up all the characters (casted as ints)
4. add up squares of characters (again casted as ints)
5. compare the sums of squares and the sums
6. if they are the same, then the strings contain the same characters.

Actually I spent some time trying to figure out where this wouldn't work, but I can't think of one. My gut tells me I'm missing something here, or this is a good comparator for this case.

Answer (score 0):

Two steps are require

1. Do xor of both strings and if xor is 0 then you are partially sure.
2. If xor is 0 then find the sum of ascii value of both strings and if ascii sum is same then 
   both strings are same.

Hope this helps