# Retrofitting void methods to return its argument to facilitate fluency: breaking change?

Tags: java, jvm, api-design, binary-compatibility

> *"API design is like sex: make one mistake and support it for the rest of your life"* <sub>([Josh Bloch on twitter](http://twitter.com/joshbloch/status/5177847605))</sub>

There are many design mistakes in the Java library. `Stack extends Vector` ([discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922257/java-stack-class-inherit-vector-class)), and we can't fix that without causing breakage. We can try to deprecate `Integer.getInteger` ([discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3123349/why-does-int-num-integer-getinteger123-throw-nullpointerexception/)), but it's probably going to stay around forever.

Nonetheless, certain kinds of retrofitting can be done without causing breakage.

> *Effective Java 2nd Edition, Item 18: Prefer interfaces to abstract classes*: Existing classes can be easily retrofitted to implement a new interface".

Examples: `String implements CharSequence`, `Vector implements List`, etc.

> *Effective Java 2nd Edition, Item 42: Use varargs judiciously*: You can retrofit an existing method that takes an array as its final parameter to take varags instead with no effect on existing clients.

An (in)famous example is `Arrays.asList`, which caused confusions ([discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467913/arrays-aslist-not-working-as-it-should)), but not breakage.

This question is about a different kind of retrofitting:

#### Can you retrofit a `void` method to return something without breaking existing code?

My initial hunch points to yes, because:

- Return type doesn't affect which method is chosen at compile time

  - See: [JLS 15.12.2.11 - Return Type Not Considered](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.12.2.11)
  - Thus, changing return type doesn't change which method is chosen by the compiler
  - Retrofitting from `void` to return something is legal (but not the other way around!)
- Even when you use reflection, things like [`Class.getMethod`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29) doesn't distinguish on return type

However, I'd like to hear a more thorough analysis by others more experienced in Java/API design.

---

#### Appendix: The Motivation

As suggested in the title, one motivation is to facilitate [fluent interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) style programming.

Consider this simple snippet that prints a shuffled list of names:

```
    List<String> names = Arrays.asList("Eenie", "Meenie", "Miny", "Moe");
    Collections.shuffle(names);
    System.out.println(names);
    // prints e.g. [Miny, Moe, Meenie, Eenie]
```

Had [`Collections.shuffle(List)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29) been declared to return the input list, we could have written:

```
    System.out.println(
        Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList("Eenie", "Meenie", "Miny", "Moe"))
    );
```

There are other methods in `Collections` that would've been much more pleasant to use if they were to return the input list instead of `void`, e.g. [`reverse(List)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse%28java.util.List%29), [`sort(List)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList(java.util.List)), etc. In fact, having `Collections.sort` and `Arrays.sort` return `void` is especially unfortunate, because it deprives us from writing expressive code such as this:

```
// DOES NOT COMPILE!!!
//     unless Arrays.sort is retrofitted to return the input array

static boolean isAnagram(String s1, String s2) {
    return Arrays.equals(
        Arrays.sort(s1.toCharArray()),
        Arrays.sort(s2.toCharArray())
    );
}
```

This `void` return type preventing fluency isn't just restricted to these utility methods, of course. The [`java.util.BitSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) methods could've also been written to return `this` (ala `StringBuffer` and `StringBuilder`) to facilitate fluency.

```
// we can write this:
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("this");
    sb.append("that");
    sb.insert(4, " & ");
    System.out.println(sb); // this & that

// but we also have the option to write this:
    System.out.println(
        new StringBuilder()
            .append("this")
            .append("that")
            .insert(4, " & ")
    ); // this & that

// we can write this:
    BitSet bs1 = new BitSet();
    bs1.set(1);
    bs1.set(3);
    BitSet bs2 = new BitSet();
    bs2.flip(5, 8);
    bs1.or(bs2);
    System.out.println(bs1); // {1, 3, 5, 6, 7}

// but we can't write like this!
//  System.out.println(
//      new BitSet().set(1).set(3).or(
//          new BitSet().flip(5, 8)
//      )
//  );
```

Unfortunately, unlike `StringBuilder`/`StringBuffer`, *ALL* of `BitSet`'s mutators return `void`.

#### Related topics

- [Method chaining - why is it a good practice, or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103985/method-chaining-why-is-it-a-good-practice-or-not)

Answer (score 15):

Unfortunately, yes, changing a `void` method to return something is a breaking change. This change will not affect source code compatibility (i.e. the same Java source code would still compile just like it did before, with absolutely no discernible effect) but it breaks binary compatibility (i.e. bytecodes that was previously compiled against the old API will no longer run).

Here are the relevant excerpts from the *Java Language Specification 3rd Edition*:

> #### [13.2 What Binary Compatibility Is and Is Not](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/binaryComp.html#13.2)
>
> Binary compatibility is not the same as source compatibility.
>
> ---
>
> ### [13.4 Evolution of Classes](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/binaryComp.html#13.4)
>
> This section describes the effects of changes to the declaration of a class and its members and constructors on pre-existing binaries.
>
> #### [13.4.15 Method Result Type](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/binaryComp.html#13.4.15)
>
> Changing the result type of a method, replacing a result type with `void`, or replacing `void` with a result type has the combined effect of:
>
> - *deleting the old method*, and
> - adding a new method with the new result type or newly `void` result.
>
> #### [13.4.12 Method and Constructor Declarations](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/binaryComp.html#13.4.12)
>
> *Deleting a method or constructor from a class may break compatibility with any pre-existing binary that referenced this method or constructor*; a `NoSuchMethodError` may be thrown when such a reference from a pre-existing binary is linked. Such an error will occur only if no method with a matching signature and return type is declared in a superclass.

That is, while the return type of a method is ignored by the Java compiler at compile-time during the method resolution process, this information is significant at run-time at the JVM bytecode level.

---

#### On bytecode method descriptors

A method's signature does not include the return type, but its bytecode descriptor does.

> #### [8.4.2 Method Signature](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.4.2)
>
> Two methods have the same signature if they have the same name and argument types.
>
> ---
>
> ### [15.12 Method Invocation Expressions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.12)
>
> #### [15.12.2 Compile-Time Step 2: Determine Method Signature](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.12.2)
>
> *The descriptor (signature plus return type)* of the most specific method is one used at run time to perform the method dispatch.
>
> #### [15.12.2.12 Example: Compile-Time Resolution](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.12.2.12)
>
> The most applicable method is chosen at compile time; its descriptor determines what method is actually executed at run time.
>
> If a new method is added to a class, then source code that was compiled with the old definition of the class might not use the new method, even if a recompilation would cause this method to be chosen.
>
> Ideally, source code should be recompiled whenever code that it depends on is changed. However, in an environment where different classes are maintained by different organizations, this is not always feasible.

A little inspection of the bytecode will help clarify this. When `javap -c` is run on the name shuffling snippet, we see instructions like this:

```
invokestatic java/util/Arrays.asList:([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/util/List;
             \______________/ \____/ \___________________/\______________/
                type name     method      parameters        return type

invokestatic java/util/Collections.shuffle:(Ljava/util/List;)V
             \___________________/ \_____/ \________________/|
                   type name        method     parameters    return type
```

#### Related questions

- [java: what is this: `[Ljava.lang.Object;`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442090/java-what-is-this-ljava-lang-object/)

---

#### On non-breaking retrofitting

Let's now address why retrofitting a new `interface` or a vararg, as explained in *Effective Java 2nd Edition*, does not break binary compatibility.

> #### [13.4.4 Superclasses and Superinterfaces](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/binaryComp.html#13.4.4)
>
> Changing the direct superclass or the set of direct superinterfaces of a class type will not break compatibility with pre-existing binaries, provided that the total set of superclasses or superinterfaces, respectively, of the class type loses no members.

Retrofitting a new `interface` does not cause the type to lose any member, hence this does not break binary compatibility. Similarly, due to the fact that varargs is implemented using arrays, this kind of retrofitting also does not break binary compatibility.

> #### [8.4.1 Formal Parameters](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.4.2)
>
> If the last formal parameter is a variable arity parameter of type `T`, it is considered to define a formal parameter of type `T[]`.

#### Related questions

- [Difference between `double…` and `double[]` in formal parameter type declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888305/difference-between-double-and-double-in-formal-parameter-type-declaration/)

---

#### Is there absolutely no way to do this?

Actually, yes, there is a way to retrofit a return value on previously `void` methods. We can't have two methods with the same exact signatures at the Java source code level, but we *CAN* have that at the JVM level, provided that they have different descriptors (due to having different return types).

Thus we can provide a binary for e.g. `java.util.BitSet` that has methods with both the `void` and non-`void` return types simultaneously. We only need to publish the non-`void` version as the new API. In fact, that's the only thing we can publish at the API, since having two methods with the exact same signature is illegal in Java.

This solution is a terrible hack, requiring special (and spec-defying) processing to compile `BitSet.java` to `BitSet.class`, and thus it may not be worth the effort to do so.

Comment: Regarding the “terrible hack”, see the [bridge-method-injector](http://bridge-method-injector.infradna.com/) tool. There are serious downsides but it works.

Answer (score 2):

If you have to deal with source compatability only, then just go ahead.  Changing from void to a return type will not break.

But to address the thing you actually want to do:
I consider the problem with fluent interfaces is that the lines tend to get rather long and - after formatting - somewhat unreadable.   For builders it works fine, but I'd probably not use it for anything else.

Is this for playing with it, or because you've found that this is really great?

Comment: "Is this for playing with it" - playing, learning, etc. Nothing serious for now.

Comment: Then do some toy stuff not used by others for now.  Especially the Builder pattern requires a lot of typing to be fully functional.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't retrofit, you still can wrap your class into a new one which uses the same methods but with correct returns (MyClassFluent).
Or you can add new methods but with different names, instead of `Arrays.sort()` we could have `Arrays.getSorted()`.

I think that the solution isn't to force things, just deal with them.

EDIT: I know I didn't answer to the "retrofitting of void methods" question, but your answer is already really clear.

Comment: Alternatives of course exist, but since some types of retrofitting to improve an API is possible (e.g. can you imagine if making `String` a `Comparable` is a breaking change???), I'd like to know where the boundaries are, and how far it can be pushed.

Comment: As you said, this kind of retrofitting isn't the "standard one". Making `String` a `Comparable` means that we *add* something, here you want to *change* something. I'm not even sure that we can call that retrofitting.

Comment: LOL I just realized that you're the one who wrote this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3550469/how-to-compare-2-strings-containing-same-characters/3550519#3550519 - yes, we 10K-ers can see deleted answers. That answer is the one that finally made me investigate this problem in greater detail. I'm glad that I'm not the only one who wished that `Arrays.sort` returns the array.

Comment: Well, the Arrays.sort() problem happens to me way too often. But I expect a returned result from a static method, not parameters updated. For example if StringBuilderUtils.toUpperCase(StringBuilder sb) existed, I would expect to get a new StringBuilder, not a modified sb and a void return.